# Logstash email alert

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to configure logstash to send mail when someone login my server. But it seems doesn't work. This is my config file in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/email.conf`

My file:

```
input {
file {
type => "syslog"
path => "/var/log/auth.log"
    }
}

filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
grok {
pattern => [ "%{SYSLOGBASE} Failed password for %{USERNAME:user} from %   {IPORHOST:host} port %{POSINT:port} %{WORD:protocol}" ]
add_tag => [ "auth_failure" ]
     }
                      }
     }

output {
email {
tags => [ "auth_failure" ]
to => "<admin@gmail.com>"
from => "<alert@abc.com>"
options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.abc.com",
            "port", "25",
            "domail", "abc.com",
            "userName", "alert@abc.com",
            "password", "mypassword",
            "authenticationType", "plain",
            "debug", "true"
            ]
subject => "Error"
via => "smtp"
body => "Here is the event line %{@message}"
htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
 }
      }
```

- My logstash file `/var/log/logstash/logstash.log`

`{:timestamp=>"2015-03-10T11:46:41.152000+0700", :message=>"Using milestone 1 output plugin 'email'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/plugin-milestones", :level=>:warn}`

any body please help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct syntax in your [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok). It should look like this:

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "..."]
}
```

Other minor comments:

- Using `tags => ["auth_failure"]` for conditional filtering is deprecated. Prefer `if "auth_failture" in [tags]`.
- In the email body you're referring to the message with `@message`. That's deprecated too and the field is named plain `message`.